# local copy of source code in version control system

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, dvcs

While working with a version control system, every collaborator has a local copy of the code base on his local machine.

1. If the version control crashes, can the VCS be restored by the code base from the collaborator's copy? If yes, how is Git different from VCS in this aspect.
2. When a collaborator updates the source code from the VCS, will he get only the delta changes patched to the existing files or he will get a new version of the files itself. Please educate me how Git is different from VCS in this aspect too.
3. One more observation I made was, if there are many developers working on a software project on VCS, and assuming that two developers Jack and Tim are working on a common feature and working on a same file. In a VCS, If Tim wants the changes of Jack to be committed for him to work, Jack is forced to commit his code. If Jacks code has some bugs, other collaborators cannot update their codebase. Hence Jack is forced to checkin his updates with proper testing only after which Tim can work on his changes. This is a bottleneck whereas in case of Git, Jack and Tim can work together on a feature branch created on Jack's repository and Tim can point to Jack's repository and fetch from Jack's repository for the common feature.. Once the feature is complete Jack can merge his and Tim's changes to the master branch.

Is my understanding correct. Please update if I am missing any other point in the above scenario.

For the sake of comparison, lets take SVN as our VCS

Regards,
Pradeep

Comment: You have to specify which version control system you have in mind when comparing to git.

Comment: lets consider SVN as the VCS

Comment: Your second question assumes a static behavior.  A proper version control system will update the files, and whether the update works by fetching the complete file or a delta will not matter much to the end user anyway, except in bandwidth consumption.  Some VCS implementations will decide case by case whether to send a patch or a complete file, depending on which will be smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in VCS in general, I am only familiar with cvs, svn and git, so others should add corrections...

Answers to your points:

1. As a distributed VCS, Git makes it straightforward to rebuild the server repository, by just cloning it, in as symmetrical way as that user could clone from the server repository.  This is because any user's repository can be as complete (if up-to-date) as the server repository.  This is not true for most other VCS (I don't know any other distributed VCS myself, other than git).

Actually, trying to restore the server from a user's local copy (using most VCSs other than git) can only restore the current state of the codebase, not its history.  On the other hand, using Git, the whole history is restored from the user repository.

2. User only gets the delta changes with respect to last parent commits available in his local repository.  This is also the typical behavior in the other VCS I know (cvs, svn).
3. Usually there is no check for code validation (e.g. code compiles ok) at commit time, so Jack could in principle checkin his (broken) code at any time, to make it immediately available to Tim.  However, this could be detrimental to other people involved, and is not considered good practice, and explicitly discouraged by company policies, coding guidelines and other such guidelines.

As an alternative, Jack could checkin his code into development branches, to minimize interference to the master branch.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. For the third point, even though JAck could check into development branches, the branch will be visible to all other developers. This might not be good since if there are 100 such branches created all of the 100 branches will be visible to all the developers. But in case of git, since the local branches can be created, it will not be visible to other developers. collaborators can point to each others remote and work on feature in a modular fashion.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  As a distributed VCS, git promotes such collaboration in much easier way than possible through any  non-distributed VCS.

Comment: The first point would generally be true for any DVCS; it is a cornerstone of such an architecture.  The local clone will contain the complete history of the project -- otherwise you are not talking about a properly distributed VCS.